# MobileFirst 8.0 DevKit - Server failed to start

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

MFP Version 8.0.0.0-MFPF-DevKit-MacOSX-IF2016082221

We have Java 1.8 installed on mac and trying to run the ./run.sh to start the local MFP server. Its failed with the below error for all context that MFP initialie.

> CWWKX0203E: The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client received an unexpected response code 502 with message 'Tunnel Connection Failed' from the server for URL https://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST on connection rest:localhost:9443 MfpRESTUser 9
>   [WARNING ] Management MBean not loaded yet, Exception: CWWKX0203E: The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client received an unexpected response code 502 with message 'Tunnel Connection Failed' from the server for URL https://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST on connection rest:localhost:9443 MfpRESTUser 9
>   CWWKX0203E: The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client received an unexpected response code 502 with message 'Tunnel Connection Failed' from the server for URL https://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST on connection rest:localhost:9443 MfpRESTUser 9

Comment: Did you check you have nothing else using 9443? Trying restarting the mac, killings the java process, ...

Comment: Hi Idan. I see its running in  http://10.241.195.109:9080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/. But its trying to use https://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST after load and failed with 'Tunnel Connection Failed'. Ports not used by other services, checked java process - nothing run and restart not helped.

Comment: Well, install the devkit on a different machine - outside your office space, still failing?

Comment: I tried in my personal mac its working fine. But office mac fails.

Comment: Ok. Then I don't know... I suggest to talk with your IT department, maybe this is some firewall rule...

Comment: Developer kit is something standalone right? Are it requires any external dependency.

Comment: There are no dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a write in the comments, if this is a fresh installation of the devkit, then the only reason for the server to not start is if some ports are already taken by an exiting process. For example another application server...

Typically a reboot of the host machine clears any such running processes, so:

1. Either restart the Mac, or
2. Kill the Java process, or
3. Quit any related running software